# deploying web application to a already started jetty

Tags: java, jetty

If I start a jetty server from an external jar using java -jar , and then how can I  add another java web application to that specific port that has already been started ? for example, this code :

```
public class Main {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        Server jettyServer = new Server(5701);
        jettyServer.setHandler(context);

        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
                org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
                "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                Calculator.class.getCanonicalName());

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
          } catch (Exception e){
                        logger.error("error during server starting",e);
              jettyServer.stop();
              jettyServer.destroy();
          }

    }
}
```

If I take the try/catch out, Would the application be added to the already existed 5701 jetty server?

Answer (score 1):

your code starts its own Jetty server on port 5701, there's nothing about that code that will add to a different Jetty server.

Lets say you have ServerFoo on port 5701 already started and running in its own JVM.

You now have another Webapp you want to add to that ServerFoo instance.

You will start a new JVM, lets call it DeployerBar, to control/manipulate the ServerFoo instance.

To do this, you need to communicate with that ServerFoo instance and give it everything it needs to start the WebApp itself (all of the classes, the configuration, etc) first.

Then ServerFoo will need a custom ClassLoader to load these new classes and configuration that it just received, giving it the ability to start this new webapp.

If this is kinda what you are looking to do, consider instead modifying ServerFoo to use the Jetty DeploymentManager to monitor a common webapps directory.

Then your deployment process is just putting all of the files (classes/jars/libs/configuration) into this common webapps directory for the ServerFoo DeploymentManager to just pick up and start using.

See [`LikeJettyXml.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/0a7ad593e43bef7aaeb0ee71e6c9f2ea7d0e7066/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java#L167-L184) for an example how this works.

```java
    DeploymentManager deployer = new DeploymentManager();
    DebugListener debug = new DebugListener(System.err,true,true,true);
    server.addBean(debug);        
    deployer.addLifeCycleBinding(new DebugListenerBinding(debug));
    deployer.setContexts(contexts);
    deployer.setContextAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$");

    WebAppProvider webapp_provider = new WebAppProvider();
    webapp_provider.setMonitoredDirName(jetty_base + "/webapps");
    webapp_provider.setDefaultsDescriptor(jetty_home + "/etc/webdefault.xml");
    webapp_provider.setScanInterval(1);
    webapp_provider.setExtractWars(true);
    webapp_provider.setConfigurationManager(new PropertiesConfigurationManager());

    deployer.addAppProvider(webapp_provider);
    server.addBean(deployer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The jetty server starts from a jar file using java -jar, and I cannot add anything to it.